# send a post to flowise ai

Tags: postman, langchain

Im running flowiseAI in a container app in Azure. Im now trying with Postman to POST some query but their documentation is very limited.Anyone got success on this ?

[image: https://1778525056-files.gitbook.io/~/files/v0/b/gitbook-x-prod.appspot.com/o/spaces%2Fy8ifwt9BYklr92KDdr48%2Fuploads%2FmxCvaNAW7XhZG4RW87qS%2Fimage.png?alt=media&token=e5ebb244-2dd0-4864-a3a6-0e0df0b1139c]